# Haskell load OpenGL texture with JuicyPixels-repa type error

Tags: opengl, haskell, types

I'm trying to load an image into an OpenGL texture, and I'm not sure how to resolve the type errors that I'm getting. Based on the error text I think somewhere in my `GL.texImage2D` call I'm goofing up, but nothing seems to be wrong here.

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL as GL
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL (($=))

import Codec.Picture.Repa as Repa

newImage fname = do
    img <- Repa.readImage fname
    case img of
        Left  _ -> return Nothing
        Right x -> do
            let (dat, w, h) = Repa.toForeignPtr . Repa.reverseColorChannel $ x

            [tex] <- genObjectNames 1
            GL.textureBinding GL.Texture2D $= Just tex
            withForeignPtr dat $ \ptr -> do
                (GL.texImage2D
                    Nothing
                    GL.NoProxy
                    0
                    GL.RGBA8
                    (GL.TextureSize2D (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h))
                    0
                    (GL.PixelData GL.RGBA GL.UnsignedByte ptr))
            return $ Just tex
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
No instance for (TwoDimensionalTextureTarget (Maybe a0))
  arising from a use of `texImage2D'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (TwoDimensionalTextureTarget (Maybe a0))
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  (texImage2D
     Nothing
     NoProxy
     0
     RGBA8
     (TextureSize2D (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h))
     0
     (PixelData RGBA UnsignedByte ptr))
In the expression:
  do { (texImage2D
          Nothing
          NoProxy
          0
          RGBA8
          (TextureSize2D (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h))
          0
          (PixelData RGBA UnsignedByte ptr)) }
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `\ ptr
     -> do { (texImage2D
                Nothing
                NoProxy
                0
                RGBA8
                (TextureSize2D (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h))
                0
                (PixelData RGBA UnsignedByte ptr)) }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [type signature of `texImage2D`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.9.0.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-Specification.html#g:8) is

```
texImage2D :: TwoDimensionalTextureTarget t
           => t -> Proxy -> Level -> PixelInternalFormat -> TextureSize2D -> Border -> PixelData a -> IO ()
```

The [instances of class `TwoDimensionalTextureTarget`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.9.0.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-Specification.html#g:6) are `TextureTargetCubeMapFace`, `TextureTargetCubeMap`, and `TextureTarget2D`.  None of these is a type synonym for any type of form `Maybe t`.  Therefore, providing `Nothing` as the first argument to `textImage2D` won't typecheck.  (There could be other errors as well - I just looked up the relevant types from the error message on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/).)

Comment: NB The code in the question is correct _if_ you are using an old version of OpenGL (2.8.0.0).  Judging by his error message, he isn't using an old version (probably using 2.9.0.0) as is this answer.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I didn't realize I was looking at old documentation. Thank you very much!